# Count rows by joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql

My query is shown below

```
select count(au.agentId), count(mr.agentId)
       from agents a
       left join assignunits au on au.agentId=a.id
       left join assignmarketreport mr on mr.agentId=a.id                        
       where a.adminsId='0' 
       and a.id='29' group BY `mr`.`agentId`, au.agentId ASC
```

I am getting value of `count(au.agentId)` same as value of `count(mr.agentId)`.

**What I want:**

For the below sample data

**assignunits**

```
agentId     status
     2      Y
     2      Y
```

**assignmarketreport**

```
agentId     status
     2      Y
     2      Y
     2      Y
```

**agents**

```
agentId     adminsId
     2      0
```

Now `count(mr.agentId)` should return `3`
and `count(au.agentId)` should return `2`

Comment: the status are equals, or different? I mean, is this real data, or just a random example?

Comment: Sort of real. I am going to fetch data with status 'Y'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 select au_agentId,mr_agentId 
  from 
          (select a.agentId,count(au.agentId) as au_agentId  
           from   agents a
           left join assignunits au 
           on     au.agentId=a.agentId
           where  a.adminsId='0'
           group  by a.agentId )au
      join
      (select a.agentId,count(mr.agentId) as mr_agentId   
       from   agents a
           left join assignmarketreport mr 
           on    mr.agentId=a.agentId
           where a.adminsId='0'
           group by a.agentId)mr  
      on    au.agentId=mr.agentId
```

## [SQl fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/564b4/3)

Comment: what if i have one more table added to this ? which has the same structure ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following,

```
SELECT  b.totalAgentUnits, c.totalAgentReport
FROM    Agents a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT agentID, COUNT(agentID) totalAgentUnits
            FROM assignunits
            GROUP BY agentID
        ) b ON a.agentID = b.agentID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT agentID, COUNT(agentID) totalAgentReport
            FROM assignmarketreport
            GROUP BY agentID
        ) c ON a.agentID = c.agentID
```

Comment: getting an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.agentId = b.agentId LEFT JOIN ( SELECT agentId, COUNT(a' at line 8`

Comment: @Deepak try it again, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Thanks it works now. If i have to add one more table of same structure as `assignunits` can i just join it using left join ?

Comment: @Deepak yes, you can do that.

Comment: For some reason @Joe G Joseph answer worked for me and your answer gave me incorrect results.. `Note:` I have added `where`  clause in the select sub queries..

Answer (score 1):

first query a 3 counts `count(units), count(marketport),count(agents)` and insert them into a count

```
count(counts `count(units), count(marketport),count(agents)`)
```

after it you may set up a php loop to get each data and display in each table

```
for($i=0;$count<3;$i++){
if($i==1){
//table 1
}
elseif($i==2){
//table 2
}
elsE{
//last table
}
}
```

an opinion only thanks